# How can I run Deno behind corporate proxy

Tags: deno

I'm trying to run `deno` on my corporate machine. So I'm behind a corporate proxy.

When I try to run a command like:

> `deno run https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts`

I get an error saying:

> Download https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts 
>   error: error sending request for url (https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)

I checked [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5296) but it's still Open and without a resolution.

I also checked [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/588) but without any luck.

There was a link pointing to some Manual in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/2873) but it's broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! So I got the link to the [manual for proxies here](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/proxies). As mentioned here:

> Deno supports proxies for module downloads and the Web standard fetch API.
>
> Proxy configuration is read from environmental variables: `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`.
>
> In case of Windows, if environment variables are not found Deno falls back to reading proxies from registry.

So I just set the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables to the proxy url(with format - `http://my-proxy-domain.com:PORT/`) and it started working.

Hope this helps others.